# Implicit ORDER BY order in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a table with a timestamp column and a few other char columns. I have ordered the information in the table by the timestamp but due to the fact that there are more records on the same timestamp I do not know if the order displayed is the order they were inserted in the table.

Sadly there is no index on the table so apart from the timestamp there isn't anything else I could use to order them by.

Example:

```
      Timestamp            |    Foregin table    |    Foreign table value

2012-10-09 19:29:50.000    |       tableA        |   "random string here"
2012-10-09 19:29:50.000    |       tableA        |   "different string here"
2012-10-09 19:29:50.000    |       tableB        |   "another random string here"
2012-10-09 19:29:50.000    |       tableC        |   "string here"
2012-10-09 19:29:50.000    |       tableD        |   "another string here"
```

The query that I run is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN 'x' and 'y'
ORDER BY Timestamp
```

Reviewing my results I assume, but I am not sure, that the query returns the data ordered by the specified column and continues ordering of the results by the next column/columns, in case there are more than 1 column, in an ascending manner (maybe by length of text or by alphabetical order).

Could you please help me clarify this situation as it is very important for me to find out the order.

Comment: There is not order of the rows in the table. There is only the order you get when specifying an `order by` and when there are duplicate values in the order by column there is nothing that guarantees the order of rows returned.

Comment: If your table happens to have some identity column, then this can (in most cases) be used to retrieve data in same order as rows were inserted. If not, then you are out of luck.

Comment: I am very out of luck, like I've said, no index column is available and no link to other indexed tables exist. I am troubleshooting a database for an application in order to figure out what queries were ran on it, and in what order. This is what the table contains and the order is very important as then I can continue my work in a correct direction. As there are around 140 queries/second it would be very hard to identify the correct order.

Comment: Using a higher resolution time source would reduce, but not eliminate, the issue.  Regardless of the resolution more than one action may occur between clock ticks.  There may also be statements that affect multiple rows and would, therefore, apply the same time to the event(s).  An identity column helps, but it can be reseeded, may have gaps where transactions were rolled back, ... .  A `rowversion` column may be more useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server in general has no order guarantee for queries not specifying an `ORDER BY`. So a `SELECT * FROM Tbl` can essentially return the rows in any random order. Because of how the data is stored on disk, if you have an empty cache and no other activity going on on the server, you will get the data in on-disk order with a fairly high probability. That probability goes down dramatically if there are other concurrent queries on your server and if the cache is not empty. So while you might observe a specific behavior in your tests, you will not get the same behavior in production.

That said, if you need the rows to come back in a specific order you need to specify an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause. In the case above you could use `ORDER BY [Timestamp], [Foreign table], [Foreign table value]` to make sure that the records always come back in the same order. If your query contains more columns and none of them is unique you need to add all those to the `ORDER BY` too. But keep in mind that sorting gets more expensive the more columns are involved.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will order the results using the explicit `ORDER BY` clause and gives no gaurantees as to the order of results for which all columns in the `ORDER BY` clause are equal.

If you want it to then order by one of your char columns alphabetically you need to specify that in your `ORDER BY` clause. It may be the case that your current results set is sorted in this way but it is highly unlikely that this will continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Tables in databases are inherently unordered.  This answer is a clarification of Sebastian's answer (the clarification is too long for a comment).

The return order is *not* random.  It is arbitrary.  And, it can change from invocation to invocation.  On a table that has deletes as well as inserts, then later records can be interspersed on data pages with earlier records.  Once again, there is no concept of ordering within a data table.  Ordering is only part of query statements.

A bigger factor than other queries running on the system is multi-threading (and to a less extant multiple partitions).

If you have an empty cache, a query that does not access the table through an index, no deletes in the table, a single partition, and a single threaded system, then the data would normally be returned in insert order.  Even in this case, though, there are no guarantees.  If you want the data in a particular order, use `order by`.  If you don't want a performance hit, include an identity primary key and use that for the ordering.

Comment: I have checked it and it is indeed arbitrary between invocations.

Comment: @reos . . . The real issue for me is that "random" has a specific technical meaning, and the results are *not* random.  They are not in a well-defined order, but that is different from randomness.